# Validation Group of many ASPxTextBox in the same time

Tags: javascript, asp.net, devexpress

I am validating some .net textboxes in javascript on focusout via regular expression:

```
ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?"
```

for all text boxes.

If isValidate, button enabled = true else button enabled = false

but my code doesn't work:

```
<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbxAcPart" runat="server" Width="95px" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s, e) {ValidTextBox(s);}" />
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" EnableCustomValidation="true"  SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Apply" Display="Dynamic" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" >
     <ErrorFrameStyle Font-Size="Smaller"/>
     <RegularExpression ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ErrorText="Numeric   !" /> 
     <RequiredField IsRequired="true" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>


<dx:ASPxTextBox ID="tbxMpPart" runat="server" Width="95px" ClientIDMode="Static">
    <ClientSideEvents Validation="function(s, e) {ValidTextBox(s);}" />
    <ValidationSettings ErrorDisplayMode="Text" EnableCustomValidation="true"  SetFocusOnError="true" ValidationGroup="Apply" Display="Dynamic" ErrorTextPosition="Bottom" >
         <ErrorFrameStyle Font-Size="Smaller"/>
         <RegularExpression ValidationExpression="[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?" ErrorText="Numeric   !" /> 
         <RequiredField IsRequired="true" />
    </ValidationSettings>
</dx:ASPxTextBox>
```

```
function ValidTextBox(s) {
    if (s.GetIsValid()) {
        decimalErr.SetText('');
    }
    else {
        decimalErr.SetText(s.GetErrorText());
        var t = document.getElementsById("btApply");
        t.disabled = true;
        this.focus();
    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly doesn't work? Does it throw error? Where? Or it just gets wrong validation result?

Answer (score 0):

If you use server control you need to use ctl.ClientID

```
function ValidTextBox(s) {

        if (s.GetIsValid()) {
            decimalErr.SetText('');
        }
        else {
            decimalErr.SetText(s.GetErrorText());
            var t = document.getElementById("<%= btApply.ClientID %>");
            t.disabled = true;
            this.focus
        }
}
```

Comment: i dont think that's the way to pass cilent id of servercontrol to java script